# Update Content builder Email - using REST API

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api

I was going through the trailhead and found this topic.

> **REST API to UPDATE CONTENT builder email**
>   https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/marketing-cloud-apis/use-rest-api-across-marketing-cloud?trail_id=develop-for-marketing-cloud

But can any one tell what I am doing wrong here!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try removing the `assetType` object from your payload. It is unnecessary and cannot be written to in update

Comment: Ah! once again Trailhead not accurate :( ...... Thanks @Gortonington it worked (y) ....... You can add this as an answer, also if it would be helpful if you can explain a bit why we need to REMOVE this section! in your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the `assetType` object from your payload. It is unnecessary and cannot be written to in update

assetType is there to define what type of item it is. (E.g. is it an image? An email? Etc) which is not necessary when updating as all this is already done via the existing asset. This info is collected via the asset Id in the url.

Now it is tossing the error because once those properties are set on creation, they cannot be changed. This is to ensure security and prevent file/asset corruption by invalid formats, etc.

Comment: Perfect! thanks for sharing the details!.